# Ubuntu Raid Issue new drive

Tags: ubuntu, raid1

I had a hard drive fail on my server.  I am pretty slow when it comes to linux so bear with me.  I replaced the drive.

I ran this:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb
```

I then ran:

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00024c28

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    50333696    25165824+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2        50335744    51384320      524288+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3        51386368  3907027120  1927820376+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00024c28

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    50333696    25165824+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2        50335744    51384320      524288+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3        51386368  3907027120  1927820376+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md2: 1974.0 GB, 1973953691648 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 481922288 cylinders, total 3855378304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Somehow I got this but, am very lost:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md2 : active raid1 sdb3[2] sda3[0]
      1927689152 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      [====>................]  recovery = 23.7% (457343168/1927689152) finish=190.9min speed=128320K/sec

md0 : inactive sda1[0](S)
      25149440 blocks super 1.2

md1 : inactive sda2[0](S)
      524032 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

I am trying to get md0 added into the raid.  I am thinking I have to wait till after this recovery finishes before I do anything else?

UPDATE1
I got a little further but am not sure about md1

```
# mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: stopped /dev/md0
# mdadm --stop /dev/md1
mdadm: stopped /dev/md1
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md2 : active raid1 sdb3[2] sda3[0]
      1927689152 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      [=====>...............]  recovery = 27.8% (536125376/1927689152) finish=179.4min speed=129207K/sec

unused devices: <none>
mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/0 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
mdadm: /dev/md/1 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).

# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 sda2[0]
      523968 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0]
      25149312 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[2] sda3[0]
      1927689152 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      [=====>...............]  recovery = 27.8% (537003968/1927689152) finish=198.8min speed=116544K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to wait until the operation finishes, you can add the other partitions now. Since you already added `sdb3` you only need to add `sdb1` and `sdb2` to their corresponding `md`s

```
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/sdb2
```

Then `cat /proc/mdstat` should show the correct status for all three partitions.

You may need to reinstall grub to both hard disks if you haven't done that already.

Comment: Thank you very much, all added and resync is delayed most likely till after that other recovery finishes.